# Relative path for JAAS keytab configuration

Tags: java, configuration, kerberos, jaas

I have a system wherein .NET clients authenticate against a Java server with Kerberos. Everything works, but I'm trying to improve the server configuration. Currently a *keytab* file is required in the root of *C:\* because my *jaas.conf* looks like this:

```
Server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    isInitiator=false
    keyTab="///C:/keytab"
    principal="XXX";
};
```

I am trying to make the `keyTab` property a relative path, but am having no luck. What I've tried:

- `keyTab="///keytab"`
- `keyTab="///./keytab"`
- `keyTab="classpath:keytab"`

All of these result in an exception, so clearly the *keytab* file cannot be found.

I've searched and [read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) and banged my head on a wall over this. Can anyone reveal the magical incantation I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `keyTab="keytab"`
Similar to the example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part1.html

Comment: Oops, I supposed it will look for the keytab in the classpath :(

Comment: that's what I thought, but no matter where I stick the keytab file, it refuses to find it without an absolute path.

Comment: I have both jaas.conf and the keytab in the same folder as the Jar I built. I am using a relative path to the keytab in jaas.conf, and it seems to be working.

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this issue ?

Comment: @TomN.Would have helped you posting the piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as well putting the keytab in the same folder as the jaas.conf file (in the conf folder). Doing keytab="keytab" would not work. Fortunately, it uses the same configuration variables used elsewhere, so the solution was to set:

```
keyTab="${catalina.base}/conf/keytab"
```