# Is it possible to reference a keytab from the classpath in jaas.conf?

Tags: java, classpath, kerberos, jaas, keytab

Is it possible to reference a keytab from the classpath in jaas.conf?

I have tried the below, but nothing seems to work:

```
Client{
keyTab=classpath: /mykeytab.keytab
}

Client{
keyTab=file: /mykeytab.keytab
}

Client{
keyTab=file: resources/mykeytab.keytab
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to use anything but an absolute path to a keytab in the jaas.conf file.

In the `Krb5LoginModule.java`, one sees (from, e.g., [Krb5LoginModule.java at github.com](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.java))

```
if (useKeyTab) {
  ktab = (keyTabName == null)
           ? KeyTab.getInstance()
           : KeyTab.getInstance(new File(keyTabName));
```

And the `.getInstance()` code will use the `.getPath()` on the instantiated `File` object (see [KeyTab.java](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/krb5/internal/ktab/KeyTab.java)).

Consequently, there is nothing in the basic approach that will search the classpath. Also, see [this question here about keytab configuration as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963494/relative-path-for-jaas-keytab-configuration).

That said, and not shown in the OP's configuration file, it is possible to change the class from the usual "com.sun.security.authmodule.Krb5LoginModule" to a custom module. In this custom module, one can then do things such as setting entries in the `Map<String,?>` parameter that is used in the `initialize` method of the `Krb5LoginModule`.

We have implemented such an approach to allow the various settings to be defined in our client application rather than trying to have our users edit a jaas.conf file on the client. So, we use a custom module that uses a Composition approach encapsulating a `Krb5LoginModule, but sets all of the desired options into the`Map`.

It is something like:

```
Map<String, String> mOpts = new HashMap<>(); // options

mOpts.put("doNotPrompt", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
mOpts.put("useTicketCache", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
mOpts.put("useKeyTab", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
mOpts.put("keyTab", options.getKeytabPath().toString());
mOpts.put("principal", PrincipalUtils.getDefaultPrincipal().getName());

krb5LM.initialize(_subject, options.getCallbackHandler(), mSS, mOpts);

//
// attempt to authenticate the user
//
krb5LM.login();
```

It is possible to search the classpath for a desired filename and then pass the found file to the `Map`. In the quasi-example above, the `options` object has pulled the keytab from the user's preferences and validated it. But rather than having a specific pre-browsed file, one could implement a search of the classpath.

Comment: Thanks much Kevin, I will take the same approach you did. Another option may be to package override the Kerberos.java present in the driver we are using and replace/alter the configuration after it is pulled in by the file.However I decided against doing it that way because it seems to "clever", which is never a good thing :p