# Spring Boot and External Resource (like keytab) Files

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I need to load few external resource files in my Spring Boot Application, something like below...

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("mongoKerberos.Keytab");
```

After spending sometime, I realized that java command (as shown below) with class path  will not work with Spring Boot jar

```
java -cp /config-location/ -jar myApplication.jar
```

After reading some literature online, I came to know about couple of options, one is to use **zip** layout (which is essentially used to create a **fat jar**) using the configurations in **spring-boot-maven-plugin** (like below) which uses org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And specify the property files in the command line as below

```
java -Dloader.path=/workspace/SpringBoot/config/ -jar SpringBoot.jar
```

The other option is to keep the default layout (which in my case would be **jar**), but change the default boot load launcher class and specify the property file location as below

```
java -Dloader.path=/workspace/SpringBoot/config/ -cp SpringBoot.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Both of the solutions are working, but I wanted to know if there are going to be any side effects (like increase in start up time or any other undesirable behavior during the runtime)

Or if there is any other better alternative solution to include exteranal resource files like keytab, some-connection-truststore.jks etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028835/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-keytab-from-the-classpath-in-jaas-conf

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam - thanks for the reply. But, the question is specific to Spring Boot configuration - how to achieve this in Spring Boot

Comment: Assuming that by "keytab" you're talking about Kerberos, the usual approach in Spring Boot is to have a property pointing to a resource URL: `myapp.keytab=file:///home/me/.config/keytab`. You can even say `@Value{"myapp.keytab"} Resource keytab`.